# How to remove scrolling glow only at one end in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to remove the scroll glowing effect on the top only. I wraped my widget by 'ScrollConfiguration', but it removed the glow on the both ends. I only need glow on the bottom side. How can I achieve this?

Here is my code,

```
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  const Body({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final daySubData = Provider.of<DaySubjects>(context);
    List<DaySubject> subList;
    switch (DateTime.now().weekday) {
      case 1:
        subList = daySubData.monSub;
        break;
      case 2:
        subList = daySubData.tueSub;
        break;
      case 3:
        subList = daySubData.wedSub;
        break;
      case 4:
        subList = daySubData.thuSub;
        break;
      case 5:
        subList = daySubData.friSub;
        break;
      case 6:
        subList = daySubData.satSub;
        break;
      case 7:
        subList = daySubData.sunSub;
        break;
    }
    return ScrollConfiguration(
      behavior: MyBehavior(),
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: subList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Column(
          children: [
            SubjectTile(subList[index]),
            // if (index != subList.length - 1) Divider(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyBehavior extends ScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Widget buildViewportChrome(BuildContext context, Widget child, AxisDirection axisDirection) {
    return child;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as an option you can wrap scroll view into NotificationListener

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(body: SafeArea(child: Content())),
    );
  }
}

class Content extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
      onNotification: (n) {
        if (n.leading) n.disallowGlow();
        return true;
      },
      child: ListView.separated(
        itemCount: 15,
        separatorBuilder: (_, __) => const Divider(),
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return Container(height: 64, alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, child: Text('ITEM $i'));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```dart
final _controller = ScrollController();
bool _flag = true;
  
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller.addListener(() {
    _flag = _controller.offset > 10;
  });
}
  
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: ListView(
      controller: _controller,
      physics: _flag ? ClampingScrollPhysics() : BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    ),
  );
}
```